# Optimal plugins and project to use IntelliJ IDEA for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, intellij-idea

I'm building a web application using a MEAN stack: [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.com/), [Express](http://expressjs.com/), [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), and [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), based on Daftmonk's [angular-fullstack](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-angular-fullstack) Yeoman generator.

Because most of my work is Java, I'm using [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) however I'd like optimal introspection and workflow for this JavaScript module.

In order to achieve to most possible introspection, and least possible confusion, what plugins and project configuration should I use?

Comment: bunch of non existing plugins here, e.g. HTML Tools, JS Support...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here's the best I've been able to do so far.

**There are some crucial IntelliJ plugins to install:**

- .gitignore support
- AngularJS
- Base64 for IDEA and Storm
- BashSupport
- Bootstrap
- CSS Support
- Database Support
- ddescriber for jasmine
- Git Integration
- GitHub
- HAML
- Heroku integration
- HTML Tools
- Jade
- JavaScript Debugger
- JavaScript Intention Power Pack
- JavaScript Support
- JS Toolbox
- JUnit
- Karma
- LESS CSS Compiler
- LESS support
- Markdown
- Mongo Plugin
- NodeJS
- Require.js plugin
- REST Client
- Spy-js
- SvgViewer 2
- Terminal
- W3C Validators
- YAML

**As a peace offering to the mighty IntelliJ, use Java as project SDK:**

[image: use Java as project SDK, to keep IntelliJ happy]

**I prefer to configure four separate modules, to help separate back-end vs. front-end JavaScript dependencies**:

[image: I prefer to configure four separate modules, to help separate back-end vs. front-end JavaScript dependencies]

Add the **bower_components** library to the **client** module, and the **node_modules** library to the **server** module:

[image: Add the bower_components library to the client module, and the node_modules library to the server module]

**And be sure to enable JavaScript libraries in the editor.**

[image: Right click in editor and choose JavaScript libraries to use]

Per best practices, we **do not commit the local IntelliJ IDEA configuration folder (`/.idea/`) to the repository**, instead adding it to the `.gitignore` file like so:

```
# IntelliJ IDEA local workspace
.idea
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Is this still true? AS in are these the only plugins we need/did any change?

Comment: This is certainly a little out of date. Any edits to the list of plugins are appreciated, thanks!